# IONIC - How to display image from firebase storage without having to download it

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-storage

After uploading the file to firebase storage, I then store it in a collection, but as I've noticed it is a download URL and not the image itself, is there a way where I can upload the image only or at least display it in the template without downloading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The download URL is just a normal URL and you can set it as the source of image.
Like in HTML `<img src="theURL" />`.

I looked up for Ionic and it looks like the syntax is:

```
<img [src]="imgurl">
```

All you have to do is get the download URL and set it as the source wherever you want to show it.

Comment: nope, like I said it doesn't work like that

Comment: @ernest_or_batchong what do you mean it doesn't work like that? Also make sure the URL is starting with `https://` and not `gs://`

Comment: by "doesn't work like that" I meant that when I try to show the image using the "img" tag it doesn't show anything meaning it's an invalid image. And yes, I have ensured that it is https://

Comment: turns out the image was corrupted